# DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message - Using buttons and embeds

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Working on a discord bot related to the pokemon game series.

I'm currently creating a menu where users can view their own pokemon team by flipping through a pages of embeds using buttons.

The initial menu embed functions fine, buttons work correctly, no errors. However when following up the basic menu command by clicking the pokemon button shown here:[image: menu command])

I get this error which crashes the bot:
`DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`

I have 2 problems here:

1. I have no idea where the empty message is coming from, the embed seems to update with the users correct pokemon, and the singular button (in this case to navigate right) is attached.
   [image: pokemon embed]
2. The button doesn't actually fire menuShowPartyRight whatsoever as i have it set up to log interactions below and nothing seems to come through.

I initially thought that the buttons might be the cause of the issue and instead tried just updating the embed itself.  But the error message persisted. Im kinda lost at this point.

```
interactionCreate.js 

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {

    if (interaction.isButton()) {

        switch (interaction.customId) {
            case 'menuShowParty':
                interaction.reply(menuShowParty(interaction.user.id, interaction.message))
                break;
            case 'menuShowPartyRight':

                console.log(interaction)
                return
                interaction.reply(menuShowParty(interaction.user.id, interaction.message, page))
                break;
            case 'menuShowPartyLeft':
                console.log(interaction)
                return
                interaction.reply(menuShowParty(interaction.user.id, interaction.message, page))
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }


})
```

```
menuShowParty.js

 exports.menuShowParty = async function menuShowParty(id, editableMessage, page) {
    const user = await getUser(id)
    const pokemonTeam = user.data.pokemon
    const showPartyEmbed = await embed({
        title: pokemonTeam[page].name + ' (' + (page + 1) + ')',
        image: pokemonTeam[page].image
    })


const showPartyButtons = new MessageActionRow()

    if (page === 5) { 
        showPartyButtons.addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('menuShowPartyLeft')
            .setLabel(pokemonTeam[page - 1].name)
            .setEmoji('⬅️')
            .setStyle('SECONDARY'))
    } else if (page === 0) {
        showPartyButtons.addComponents( 
        new MessageButton()
        .setCustomId('menuShowPartyRight')
        .setLabel(pokemonTeam[page + 1].name)
        .setEmoji('➡️')
        .setStyle('SECONDARY'))
    } else { 
        showPartyButtons.addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('menuShowPartyLeft')
            .setLabel(pokemonTeam[page - 1].name)
            .setEmoji('⬅️')
            .setStyle('SECONDARY'),
            new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('menuShowPartyRight')
            .setLabel(pokemonTeam[page + 1].name)
            .setEmoji('➡️')
            .setStyle('SECONDARY'))
    }
    
    
    
    return editableMessage.edit({
        embeds: [showPartyEmbed],
        components: [showPartyButtons]
    })

}
```

```
menu.js

module.exports = {
    name: 'menu',
    description: 'Accesses the main menu of the pokebot.',

    minArgs: 0,
    maxArgs: 0,
    expectedArgs: '',

    aliases: ['m'],
    permissions : [''],
    /**
     *
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    run: async (client, message, args) => {

        const user = message.author.id
        const userData = users[users.findIndex(x => x.id == user)]

        const menuEmbed = await embed({title: `Main Menu`})
        menuEmbed.setAuthor(`${message.author.username}'s menu`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        menuEmbed.addField('Current Balance', `\`${userData.data.credits}\``)

        let availiblePokemon = userData.data.pokemon.length
        for(i = 0; i < userData.data.pokemon.length; i++) {
            if (userData.data.pokemon[i].fainted == true) {
                availiblePokemon--
            }
        }

        menuEmbed.addField('Availible Pokemon', `\`${availiblePokemon}/${userData.data.pokemon.length}\``)

        const pokeballEmoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'pokeball');
        const backpackEmoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'backpack');
        const menuButtons = new MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('menuShowParty')
            .setLabel('Pokemon')
            .setStyle('DANGER')
            .setEmoji(pokeballEmoji),
            new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('menuShowMap')
            .setLabel('Map')
            .setStyle('SUCCESS')
            .setEmoji('️'),
            new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('menuOpenBag')
            .setLabel('Bag')
            .setStyle('PRIMARY')
            .setEmoji(backpackEmoji),
            new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('findMultiplayerBattle')
            .setLabel('Battle')
            .setStyle('SECONDARY')
            .setEmoji('')
        );
        
       message.reply({embeds:[menuEmbed], components:[menuButtons]})

    },
};
```

Comment: Try adding a description to your embeds or change `.setTitle()` to `.setDescription()` if you don't want any extra text. You can always add `**` before and after text to make it bold eg. `.setTitle('Main Menu')` looks the same as `.setDescription('**Main Menu**')` so long as only one is used, if both are used, just looks like two titles.

Comment: so i added a set description line, and commented out the title line, and i got this [link](https://imgur.com/a/2BnZ1oM) however im still receiving the empty message error

Comment: believe i was able to solve the issue, had to do with the interaction.reply() not liking only a message.edit() action being passed through.